How to expand button to full-width on smaller screen sizes?
I have the following markup:
<div class="ml-auto text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-next mobile" />
</div>

And css:
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .mobile {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

I would like to display the button aligned right on desktop and expand to full width on mobile.
However, the above is not working.
What is the correct way to achieve this?

I don't think the issue is with the code here. Can you show the css you use on desktop?

The provided code does not affect your requirement. You need to add CSS to the button div container. Have you tried anything on that line? One way would be use flex.

@DarshnaRekha Can you provide a snippet?

Your markup is invalid. The <button> tag is not self closing.

In the example below, the media query is suggested for extra small devices max-width. There are two <button>s and each one has a <div> wrapped around them. One <div> will be visible while the other is display: none.
The necessary Bootstrap classes are:

Desktop

.d-flex

.justify-content-end


<div class="d-flex justify-content-end"></div>


Mobile

.d-grid

<div class="d-grid"></div>



The custom classes .desktop and .mobile must be doubled for higher specificity as well as using !important in order to override the BS classes. The Bootstrap Icons are of course optional.
View in Full page mode and resize the window.


.mobile.mobile {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .desktop.desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .mobile.mobile {
    display: grid !important;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
   /*
     Custom CSS can go here or externally as the last <link>
  */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="p-3 d-flex justify-content-end desktop">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-next">
            Next <i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-3 d-grid mobile">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-next">
            Next <i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>




by using the common mobile-first approach you can simplify things:
here's the pen

/* defaults to full width */
.mobile {
  width: 100%;
}

/* changes when certain dimensions is passed - note how we changed this from "max-with" to "min-width" */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .mobile {
    width: auto;
  }
}


Try this updated CSS, use the parent class to avoid any conflict
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
      .mobile {
        width: 100%;           
        margin: 0 auto;        
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;  
        display: block;        
        text-align: center;   
      }
    
      .ml-auto {
        margin-left: auto;    
      }
    
      .text-right {
        text-align: initial;
      }
    }


The provided code does not affect your requirement. You need to add CSS to the button div container.
In the HTML add a class for button container div.
<div class="ml-auto text-right button-container">
    <button class="btn btn-next mobile">Next</button>
</div>

Add the CSS for the container to be right aligned in desktop. Your mobile media query handles the mobile screen where it will occupy the full width.
.button-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .mobile {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .button-container {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

I have tried the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/rekhaDarshna/yv4fg9ew/
Let me know if there is anything missing.



.mybtn {
            display: block;
            background-color: green;
            color: beige;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 30px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            border: none;
        }
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                                   initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Full Width Button</title>
    
    </head>

<body>
    <button class="mybtn">
        Full Width Button
    </button>

</body>

</html>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
